# Optimize regex for maximum speed

Tags: regex, performance, optimization, cpu-usage

Please help me to optimize following regex to best performance . I have read some articles but this problem should solve quickly to decrease cpu usage and delay time so i don't have enough time for try and false .

First one should match for example

`http://microsoft.com/test/temp.iso`

`http://download.microsoft.com/TEMP.iso`

**note**:

- *All url should start with `http://`  so i don't know it is better to put `^http://` at first or not ?*
- *first line and last line have specific rules but lines between them may combined.*

Any help appreciated .

```
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)(microsoft|windowsupdate).com/.*\.(cab|exe|dll|ms[i|u|f]|asf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip|iso|psf) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)eset.com/.*\.(cab|exe|dll|ms[i|u|f]|asf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip|ver|nup) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)avg.com/.*\.(cab|exe|dll|ms[i|u|f]|asf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip|ctf|bin|gz) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)grisoft.(com|cz)/.*\.(cab|exe|dll|ms[i|u|f]|asf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip|ctf|bin|gz) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)avast.com/.*\.(cab|exe|dll|ms[i|u|f]|asf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip|vpx|vpu|vpa|vpaa|def|stamp) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)(kaspersky-labs|kaspersky).com/.*\.(cab|zip|exe|msi|msp|bz2|avc|kdc|klz|dif|dat|kdz|kdl|kfb) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)nai.com/.*\.(gem|zip|mcs|tar|exe|) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)adobe.com/.*\.(cab|aup|exe|msi|upd|msp) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)symantecliveupdate.com/.*\.(zip|exe|msi) 
refresh_pattern -i (.+\.||)(192\.168\.10\.34|mywebsite.com)/.*
```

Edit: these regexp are used in [squid configuration](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/)

Comment: This would be something for code-review.

Comment: which language/tool are you using?mention it in your question!Someone could come with a good non-regex solution!

Comment: Since Omid Kosari might be knew and not know about it, Games Brainiac talks about **[code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)**.

Comment: `(.+\.||)` can be distilled down to `(.+\.)?` and is probably not necessary anyway. And adding the EOL anchor `$` to each expression might help. Also, for brevity, convert all your meta dots to literals, ie: to `nai\.com`

Comment: You are right i didn't know about Code Review . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A couple tips for optimizing your regexes:

First, the use of `.*` may cause performance problems, depending on the size of the strings you are matching and how early your matches typically end in the strings. Try `.*?` and see if it helps. If you know more details about the nature what the `.` will match, it may be possible to find an even faster replacement.

Second, if your regex engine supports it, and you don't actually need to extract the capturing groups from the match, you can make them non-capturing. This gives a small but consistent performance boost. In Ruby, a non-capturing group looks like: `(?:PUT CONTENTS HERE)`.

One point of advice: you say you want to "solve this problem quickly" but "don't have time" for trial and error. I'm sorry, but if you want the best performance, you will have to do your own benchmarking and find what is fastest in your language, and on your data set. All people like me can do is give you some suggestions of what things to try as you benchmark alternate solutions.

Comment: Thanks . very useful . i hope other provide more answer else your answer will accepted .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on programming language you could compile this regex at program start and then just reuse the regex object. In C# it looks like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Compiling regex takes a little more time, but if you use it couple of times, it worth it.

Comment: Thanks but it is not in programming language . it is in squid configuration file .